# Error: Driver is already registered, aborting

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have written a serial uart driver in linux and have the kernel log with this :

`[  242.880615] Error: Driver 'my-uart' is already registered, aborting...`

I have checked the DTS file and found no issues with it(single instance of UART). I have checked the serial_core.c code also and found no match for that.

What may be causing this issue?

Comment: I guess it means your code is trying to register the driver when it is already registered. Show the code.

Comment: I have tried to remove a register but still I get the same error. [Link](https://gitlab.com/venkatakrishs/linux-device-drivers/-/blob/master/shakti-uart.c)

Comment: You should register both the platform driver and the uart driver in the module init function.

Comment: Oh. which means that the probe is to setup the hardware while the module init and module exit function is the only to register and unregister from the serial core. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @IanAbbott I have made the changes as you have mentioned and still I have the same issue happening in the console. _**[  210.235565] Error: Driver 'shakti-uart' is already registered, aborting...**_ [Link](https://gitlab.com/venkatakrishs/linux-device-drivers/-/blob/master/shakti-uart.c)

Comment: I don't know what the problem is now. There is a left-over call to `uart_unregister_driver` at the end of `shakti_uart_probe`, which is a bug, but unrelated to the "already registered" error.

Comment: Actually, I think I have spotted the problem. The `arch_initcall(shakti_uart_init);` and the `module_platform_driver(shakti_uart_driver);` both set up entry points into the module that both register the platform driver.

Comment: The call to `uart_unregister_driver` is when the probe fails in the driver. And when there is successful probing of the driver it will return 0 at line [752](https://gitlab.com/venkatakrishs/linux-device-drivers/-/blob/master/shakti-uart.c#L752) I will remove and check on the module_platform_driver call.

Comment: Thanks @IanAbbott that issue is resolved now.

Comment: Also @IanAbbott the uart driver once probed is waiting for a key to be pressed so that it can continue which creates a time delay(in the kernel output) `[    1.655151] 11300.uart: ttySHAKTI0 at MMIO 0x11300 (irq = 0, base_baud = 0) is a Shakti UART 0
[ 5997.536315] printk: console [ttySHAKTI0] enabled
` see the timings. Is this the default behavior of the uart driver?

Comment: It seems unusual behavior for it to delay about 100 minutes before enabling the console. Also, the presence of the string `printk:` in the message is unusual.

Comment: The computer waits after probing the uart driver and when I press any key it continues to print from that time thats the reason for that time delay(which can change depending on the time taken to press a key). I also feel that the unusual `printk:` is the one making the console only for printk messages while the normal printf messages from syslogd and all (and even the login prompt) are not being printed(displayed)